# ¿Como hacer un botón de ir abajo con HTML y JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

En estos días e estado haciendo un pequeño proyecto y ya hice un botón de ir arriba ahora me pregunto como hacer uno de ir hacia abajo y quisiera saber como hacerlo con html, javascript para luego darle estilo con css y colocarle un icono con FontAwesome

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero revisar la sección de [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para que tu preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad. También puedes revisar [como crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tan facil como decir `<a href="#footer">ir abajo</a>` donde en href indicara a donde se quiere ir. Para ser mas claro mira este ejemplo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
    var destino = $(this.hash); //this.hash lee el atributo href de este
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: destino.offset().top }, 700); //Llega a su destino con el tiempo deseado
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
div{
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 2000px;
}
footer{
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  tu contenido
  <a href="#footer">ir abajo</a>
</div>
<footer id="footer">
   la parte de abajo
</footer>
```

El script solo le agrega la animacion al scroll

Comment: Buen aporte +1, aunque podrías explicar cómo funciona el código `jQuery` en sí, que hace por ejemplo `$(this.hash)`, etc. Ayudaría a entender mejor el ejemplo para usuarios que no tienen conocimiento en `jQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

Lo mas sencillo es que te crees unos elementos (por ejemplo un `hr`) con `id`'s justo despues de abrir y cerrar el `body` y añadas enlaces a esos `id`'s con `#`

Al clickar en esos enlaces, la pagina hará scroll hasta mostrarlos en pantalla lo más arriba posible.

```css
main {
  background: yellow;
  height: 1000px;
}

header {
  background: green;
  height: 70px;
}

footer {
  background: blue;
  height: 70px;
}

hr.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.scrollNavigation {
  position: fixed;
  left: 20px;
  background: black;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}

a.scrollNavigation[href="#top"] {
  top: 20px;
}

a.scrollNavigation[href="#bottom"] {
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <hr id="top" class="hidden" />

  <header></header>
  <main></main>
  <footer></footer>

  <hr id="bottom" class="hidden" />

  <a class="scrollNavigation" href="#top">↑ Go Top</a>
  <a class="scrollNavigation" href="#bottom">↓ Go Bottom</a>
</body>
```